# How to load all comments of a website via selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I want to scrape all comments (~7000) from https://www.focus.de/gesundheit/news/coronavirus-news-trump-prahlt-mit-allumfassender-macht_id_11576018.html. As the website does not show all comments, but gives only the possibility to load 10 comments a time, i try to load all comments with selenium in python and then give the output to BeautifulSoup.

The HTML segment of the website that corresponds with the button "Weitere Kommentare (10)" and which loads the next 10 comments is:

```
<div id="further_comments" class="getMoreComments">                 
    <a rel="1" class="moreComments bluebutton">
         <span>Weitere Kommentare (10)</span>
    </a>                        
</div>
```

It loads the next ten comments (second div below, only one shown here instead of ten) and a new button for loading another 10 comments (a):

```
<div class="moreComments">
    <div class="comment clearfix open oid-15051615"</div>
    <div class="getMoreComments">
        <a class="moreCommentsAjx bluebutton" rel="1"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

My approach was to write a script that automatically clicks "Weitere Kommentare (10)", waits until the next 10 comments and the next button "Weitere Kommentare (10)" is loaded, finds the button, clicks it again... until all comments are loaded. My attempt was following (I center the button to avoid a pop-up at the bottom of the page, which would obscure the button):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException, NoSuchElementException

ignored_exceptions = (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException)

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get('https://www.focus.de/gesundheit/news/coronavirus-news-trump-prahlt-mit-allumfassender-macht_id_11576018.html')
driver.fullscreen_window()

button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("moreComments.bluebutton")
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: "center", inline: "center"})', button)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)

while driver.find_element_by_class_name("moreCommentsAjx.bluebutton"):
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10, ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "moreCommentsAjx.bluebutton")))
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: "center", inline: "center"})', element)
    element.click()

page_source = driver.page_source
```

Unfortunately that code never goes through. At some point the button "Weitere Kommentare (10)" just does not appear anymore and a "NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: .moreCommentsAjx.bluebutton" is thrown (weirdly despite it being supposed to ignore it). What puzzles me is, it´s not systematic. Sometimes it manages to load a couple hundreds comments before it fails, sometimes only 30 etc. Occasionally a StaleElementReferenceException is thrown (again it should not, but it does), when the scrolling seems to fail and does not center the button, but that's seldom.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: where does it fail? in the while line or in the line where you wait?

Comment: @INDIVIDUAL-IT the element.click() fails, which is the weird thing. Initially it finds the element, because it enters the while-loop, but then within the loop the element isn´t there anymore (the website does not display the button).

Comment: see my answer below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/61227265/4501350)

Answer (score 0):

You might be waiting "wrongly"

After the click you wait till the button is there, but maybe its still there and haven't gone yet.

After the click you want to wait till the button disappears (but not fail and having a very short time-out) and then you want to wait till the button appears again.

Comment: If i understand you correctly, then adding a time.sleep (i tried 3 seconds) after the element.click() could solve the problem, but sadly it doesn't. Again at some (random) point in time no new button appears on the website and the click fails.

Comment: Before the click try to wait for `element_to_be_clickable` and after the click `invisibility_of_element_located` see https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

I would not ignore exceptions in the wait before the click, you want to know if that waiting fails for some reason, the wait after the click should have a low timeout e.g. 5sec (so you waste max 5 sec) and there you can ignore exceptions in the case the button went and came quicker that you checked

Comment: Adding  `WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,"moreCommentsAjx.bluebutton")))` after the click gives me a timeout. Apparently the new buttons loads so fast, that it never goes invisible. I read this could be due to driver.implicitly_wait, but deleting it doesn't change that.

Comment: try to ignore the timeout exception, is actually throwing an exception?

Comment: I get "TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ignored_exception'" if i try to ignore timeouts. I could catch the timeout but i don't know if that gets me any further.